# Energy density of magnetostatic fields

Tags: energy, magnetostatics

Consider that we are given magnetostatic field $B=B_1$ and $\frac{dB}{dt}=0$ from the beginning of time to the end of time. We are interested in the potential energy contained in the field.

We know that $$dU=H{\cdot}dB$$ where $U$ is energy density and $B={\mu}H$.

There is a person who approached the problem as follow:

Because of that the magnetic field is constant then he set $dB=0$ and he puts it in the integral $$\begin{aligned}U&={\int}HdB\\&=\frac{1}{\mu}{\int}BdB\\&=\frac{1}{\mu}\int B\cdot0\\&=0\end{aligned}$$

So the person concluded that magnetostatic field does not have energy (does not contain potential energy at all).

The person did not allow me to perform the following integral $$\begin{aligned}U&={\int_0^{B_1}}HdB\\&=\frac{1}{\mu}{\int_0^{B_1}}BdB\\&=\frac{1}{2\mu}B_1^2\end{aligned}$$

Because, he said that the magnetic field is constant and has never changed from $0$ to $B_1$. For the integral from $0$ to $B_1$ to be valid $B$ must change from $0$ to $B_1$ he argued.

I need some comments.

Comment: You should have a look to : 
http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_17.html#Ch17-S8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation

$$ dU = H \cdot dB $$

is valid only in context of [virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) and should be considered a differential equation determining the function $U(B)$. It tells you how would $U$ change if one changed $B$ by $dB$. So you are right and he is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is constant once it has been established.   But it takes energy to establish the field, and while it's being established the field is not constant.   The integral that you present is the energy required to establish the field, and gives the correct energy.    $\frac{1}{2\mu}B^2$ is the energy required to establish the constant field $B$.

Comment: Even if the field decreases from $B_1$ to $B$ ($B_1 > B$) (does not increase from $0$ to $B$), the energy density stored in the field is still computed by integrating $H = \frac1{\mu}B$ with respect to $B$ from zero to $B$.